# Magnetic moment of current loop

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

From what I have learnt, the magnetic moment of a current carrying loop is
$$\pmb{\mu} = NI \mathbf{A}.$$

But what is written in this book *Modern atomic and nuclear physics* by Fuzia Yang, I am not able to understand.

> **4.1.1 Classical Expression**
>
> It is well known in classical electromagnetism that the mangetic moment $\mu$ associated with a small electric current may be expressed as (see Fig. 4.1(a))
> $$\pmb{\mu} = \frac{i}{c} S \mathbf{n}_0$$
> where $i$ is the electric current in the sense of positive charge flow, $c$ is the speed of light ($c=1$ in this equation in "reduced" units based on the SI system of units), $S$ is the area enclosed by the current circuit, and $\mathbf{n}_0$ is a unit vector normal to the plane of the circuit.

It would be great help if somebody could provide a clue for how the two are connected.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> From what I have learnt, the magnetic moment of a current carrying loop is
> $$\pmb{\mu} = NI \mathbf{A}.$$

> But what is written in this book *Modern atomic and nuclear physics* by Fuzia Yang, I am not able to understand.
> **4.1.1 Classical Expression**
>
> > It is well known in classical electromagnetism that the mangetic moment $\mu$ associated with a small electric current may be expressed as (see Fig. 4.1(a))
> > $$\pmb{\mu} = \frac{i}{c} S \mathbf{n}_0$$
> > where $i$ is the electric current in the sense of positive charge flow, $c$ is the speed of light ($c=1$ in this equation in "reduced" units based on the SI system of units), $S$ is the area enclosed by the current circuit, and $\mathbf{n}_0$ is a unit vector normal to the plane of the circuit.

He is just using different symbols and considering only one loop winding (not $N$ windings). He is also using different units and, as he writes, you can set $c$ to 1 to convert to "reduced" SI units.

The translation of symbols from the bottom equation to the top equation is:
$$
S\mathbf n_0 \to \mathbf A
$$
$$
i \to I
$$
$$
c \to 1
$$

Comment: Ok but are the two equations dimensionally same? As one of them has speed of light in the denominator.